# Issues with Oracle Query execution time

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

Below is my query, I use four joins to access data from three different tables, now when searching for 1000 records it takes around 5.5 seconds, but when I amp it up to 100,000 it takes what seems like an infinite amount of time, (last cancelled at 7 hours..)

Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong? Or what could be done to speed up the query?

This query will proabably end up having to be run to return millions of records, I've only limited it to 100,000 for the purpose of testing the query and it seems to fall over at even this small amount.

For the record im on oracle 8

```
CREATE TABLE co_tenancyind_batch01 AS
SELECT  /*+ CHOOSE */ ou_num,
x_addr_relat,
x_mastership_flag,
x_ten_3rd_party_source
FROM s_org_ext,
s_con_addr,
s_per_org_unit,
s_contact
WHERE s_org_ext.row_id = s_con_addr.accnt_id
AND s_org_ext.row_id = s_per_org_unit.ou_id
AND s_per_org_unit.per_id = s_contact.row_id
AND x_addr_relat IS NOT NULL
AND rownum < 100000
```

Explain Plan in Picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDmN2.jpg (easy to read)

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns you use in joins and condition?

Comment: Yes they are all indexed

Comment: Can you post the explain plan of the select statement ? @AleksG

Comment: Will do give me a second

Comment: http://imgur.com/Xw9x4BA Explain plan @brhneser

Comment: It looks like are running the rule-based optimizer. Switching to the cost-based optimizer might help, especially if the optimizer can choose a plan with hash joins. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58246/optimiz.htm#322

Comment: You have a full table access on `siebl.s_contact` in that plan.

Comment: How would I go about not making it a full table access, I just want it to take rows from s_contact where the joins match.

Comment: The full table scan is not a problem in this context as the other joins are nested loop and there is a stopkey -- as soon as the required row count has been met the scan will be stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test based on 100,000 rows is not meaningful if you are then going to run it for many  millions. The optimiser knows that it can satisfy the query faster when it has a stopkey by using nested loop joins.

When you run it for a very large data set you're likely to need a different plan, with hash joins most likely. Covering indexes might help with that, but we can't tell because the selected columns are missing column aliases that tell us which table they come from. You're most likely to hit memory problems with large hash joins, which could be ameliorated with hash partitioning but there's no way the Siebel people would go for that -- you'll have to use manual memory management and monitor v$sql_workarea to see how much you really need.

(Hate the visual explain plan, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can you make sure there is an index on S_CONTACT table and it is enabled ?

If it is so, try the select statement with /*+ CHOOSE */ hint and have another look at the explain plan to see if optimizer mode is still RULE. I believe cost based optimizer would result better in this query.

If still rule try updating database statistics and try again. You can use DBMS_STATS package for that purpose, if i am not wrong it was introduced with version 8i. Are you using 8i ?

And at last, i don't know the record numbers, the cardinality between tables. I might have been more helpful if i knew the design.

Comment: CREATE TABLE co_tenancyind_batch01 AS
SELECT  /*+ CHOOSE */ ou_num,
x_addr_relat,


I've added the choose after the select and now the optimizer section of the explain plan reads "Hint: Choose" instead of Rule is this correct?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/547/htmq.jpg/ this is currently what my query and explain plan looks like. @brhneser

Comment: Will try running it now @brhneser

Comment: But still there is no index usage for table s_contact and lots of merge_joins going on, I think it would still be not ok. Did you check the index on s_contact ? You might need to rebuild it. If index is ok, you can try forcing the usage with a hint

Comment: Can'tread that plan image. Can you just "select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)"?

Comment: The full table scan on s_contact is not a problem in this context if the other joins are nested loop and there is a stopkey -- as soon as the required row count has been met the scan will be stopped.

Comment: Will try and do that now @David Aldridge

Comment: I get an invalid column name error when using select * from table(dbms_xplan.display) @ David Aldridge

Comment: @DavidAldridge  But still, that index might have lead to a hash join rather than a Nested Loop i think, no ? What i think is statistics need to be updated, especially for COB. So that Oracle may be able to choose join algorithms properly. On the other hand, the Oracle version is and old one, and the tables might be really huge.

Comment: @brhneser all of the tables are pretty huge minimum 20 million rows. maximum probably close to 100 million

Comment: @brhneser updating statistics on a Siebel system is a Big Deal -- I'd recommend optimiser dynamic sampling instead, if that was really an issue. I think the lack of hash join is due to the stopkey really. Callum what's your full Oracle version?

Comment: Oh hash joins might be explicitly disabled through the relevant init parameter - worth checking, as I think you can override at the session level. Best keep the DBA's informed if you plan on doing that or on switching to manual memory management.

Comment: I don't think I'm qualified or experienced enough to start manual memory managment, I'm still pretty fresh to Oracle in general. coming mainly from an SAP background. @David Aldridge

Comment: @DavidAldridge I see, not really having any knowledge about Siebel System. Hash joins can be forced using USE_HASH btw. But more knowledge about tables would be required to write a query with hints.

Comment: @brhneser I'd expect the optimiser to make a good choice on that without hints, but there is, or was in some versions, an init parameter to disable them completely.

Comment: @Callum I'd suggest just using the query you want without the stopkey, seeing what the plan is, and letting the explain plan estimate the size of the required temp space -- that will give a good idea of whether manual memory management is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset, looking at the last execution plan appear to be huge, you could limit access to the base table instead of limiting the number of returned row, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE co_tenancyind_batch01 AS
SELECT  /*+ CHOOSE */ ou_num,
x_addr_relat,
x_mastership_flag,
x_ten_3rd_party_source
FROM s_org_ext,
s_con_addr,
s_per_org_unit,
(select * from s_contact where rownum <= 100000) cont
WHERE s_org_ext.row_id = s_con_addr.accnt_id
AND s_org_ext.row_id = s_per_org_unit.ou_id
AND s_per_org_unit.per_id = cont.row_id
AND x_addr_relat IS NOT NULL
```

should improve but not be extremely quick.

Comment: but what if from the 100,000 s_contact rows selected, none of them match the joins?

Comment: if you need the complete dataset, I would split the query in multiple parts, adding range conditions on s_contact.row_id. An initial create table as select, then multiple insert into co_tenancyind_batch01  select ....

Comment: also you could move a the largest full scan in a subquery and add a parallel hint on it.